# Converting swift array into object for json serialization

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2

The following code does not compile in Swift 2.0

```
var eventsIds : [CalendarEventLink?] = [CalendarEventLink?](count: 5, repeatedValue: nil)
var data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(eventsIds, options: [])
```

I'm getting error:

> '[CalendarEventLink?]' is not convertible to '[AnyObject]'

How can I serialise array to json in swift?

Comment: `[CalendarEventLink?](count: 5, repeatedValue: nil)` creates an array of 5 x `nil`: `[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]`, but you can't encode `nil` into JSON.

Comment: You have to be able to unwrap this in order for it to be serializable. You can try it with an `if...let` to decide if it is not an optional.

Comment: So basically, you say that the elements of an swift array must be not optional to be able to used as json object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var eventsIds : [CalendarEventLink] = []
var data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(eventsIds, options: [])
```

As mentioned in comments above, you can't send array of optional items into [AnyObject]